# csv.writer won't close when writing things into an excel csv file

Tags: python, excel, file, csv, concatenation

I am trying to compile many csv files into one large one. When I run my program (below) it fills the first rows of the designated CSV file with the correct info, but then it starts variably spacing the data and leaving empty cells. It also doesn't stop filling the csv file, it is continuous. The combined data should be a few thousand KB, but it didn't stop even after it hit 5 million KB and didn't even input all the data I needed. Dir variable defined as importing csv files.

I have tried adding a wf.close() statement at the end of the code, but I am left with the message "AttributeError: '_csv.writer' object has no attribute 'close'"

```
csv_file_list = glob.glob(Dir + '/*.csv')
wf = csv.writer(open(Avg_Dir + '.csv','w'),delimiter = ',') #wb to w

for files in csv_file_list:
    #print (files) #debug, confirmed
    rd = csv.reader(open(files,'r'),delimiter = ',')
    #rd.next()
    for row in rd:
        print (row) #debug, confirmed
        wf.writerow(row)
```

I tried writing a with statement as well, and I am having the same issue, it runs fine for a while, then starts printing empty cells in my combined csv file, and doesn't close. I'm mainly trying to figure out how to close this so my combined csv file has the right information and is not endlessly being added to.

Comment: well it helps if you close it

Comment: As @SuperStew suggested you need to close the file once you are done (outside the loop)

Comment: @Cabrra how do I close it? I tried the wf.close statement and that didn't work, and I tried a with statement and that didn't seem to work either

Answer (score 0):

Use [with statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) for open and close csv file automatically

```py
with open(path, 'w') as file:
    w = csv.writer(file)
    ...
```